# Discretely selecting the variables/columns I want in the parallel coordinate plot, and setting it so that this legend also displays the actual value

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggally

I am currently analysing the `Auto` data from the [ISLR package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ISLR/ISLR.pdf). I want to produce a parallel coordinate plot of the variables `mpg`, `cylinders`, `displacement`, `horsepower`, `weight`, `acceleration`, and `year`. My plot is as follows:

```
library(GGally)

parcoord = ggparcoord(Auto.df, columns = 1:7, mapping = aes(color = as.factor(origin)), title = "Complete Auto Data") + scale_color_discrete("origin", labels = levels(Auto.df$origin))
print(parcoord)
```

[image]

Notice that I have stated `columns = 1:7`. It just so happens that the variables I want are in consecutive columns in the `Auto` dataset. But what if they weren't, and I wanted to discretely select the variables/columns?

Furthermore, notice that I have set the variable `origin` to be a factor, and then placed it as a legend on the side. As you can see, the three values of `origin` are in different colours. However, the actual value of `origin` (`1`, `2`, `3`) is not displayed next to the colour, so we can't tell which colour is associated to which value. How do I set it so that this legend also displays the actual value?

Comment: The documentation for ggparacord suggests you can pass a vector of variable names to the function a la `columns = c("mpg", "cylinders", "displacement")`.

Answer (score 4):

For selecting the columns, you must pass a a vector of column indices. To display values in the legend, just remove `labels = levels(Auto.df$origin)` from the `scale_color_discrete`.
Here is the new code:

```
data(Auto)
parcoord <- ggparcoord(Auto, columns = c(1,5,7), 
                       mapping = aes(color = as.factor(origin)), 
                       title = "Complete Auto Data") + 
  scale_color_discrete("origin")

print(parcoord)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

At the beginning, I suggest that you convert the variable `origin` to `factor` even before using the data to prepare the plot. So do like this:

```
library(ISLR)
library(tidyverse)
library(GGally)

data(Auto)
Auto.df = Auto %>% as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(origin = origin %>% paste %>% fct_inorder)
```

Now you can prepare the chart like this:

```
Auto.df %>% 
  ggparcoord(columns = 1:7, 
             groupColumn="origin", 
             mapping = aes(color = origin), 
             title = "Complete Auto Data")
```

[image]

When you want to analyze only selected columns (e.g. 2, 5 and 7) do it like this:

```
Auto.df %>% 
  ggparcoord(columns = c(2,5,7), 
             groupColumn="origin", 
             mapping = aes(color = origin), 
             title = "Complete Auto Data")
```

[image]

The last way to select variables and their order, perhaps more readable, at least for me, might be:

```
Auto.df %>% select(displacement, mpg, weight, origin) %>% 
  ggparcoord(columns = 1:3,
             groupColumn="origin",
             mapping = aes(color = origin),
             title = "Complete Auto Data")
```

[image]

This solution greatly simplifies what you want to do and does not require the use of the `scale_color_discrete` function. I hope this is the effect you wanted. That if it does not fully suit your needs, please write a comment.